# How to copy(get) URL of startpage's result page?

Tags: firefox, browser, webpage

How to copy(get) URL of startpage's result page?

For example:

URL of result page for duckduckgo:
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=test&t=ffsb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to copy(get) URL of startpage's result page?

Do one of the following:

- Use the "Bookmark this search" button on the right of the results page
- Switch off "Use POST vs GET" completely in the [settings](https://www.startpage.com/do/preferences?language_ui=hangul&jump_to=post_setting&#post_setting#hmb)

> **Q: I cannot make a shortcut of a search result to my desktop.**
>
> Every
> new shortcut produces just another blank page. What's wrong?
>
> Contrary
> to other search engines StartPage uses the so-called POST method
> (instead of the GET method) to keep your search terms out of the logs
> of webmasters of sites that you reach from our results. Search terms
> tell a lot about what you are thinking, which is why this is a privacy
> issue. With the POST method StartPage uses, your search terms are
> stripped off causing this effect. To create shortcuts you can use the
> "Bookmark this search" button on the right of the results page.
> Alternatively you can switch off "Use POST vs GET" completely in the
> [settings](https://www.startpage.com/do/preferences?language_ui=hangul&jump_to=post_setting&#post_setting#hmb).

Source [FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS](https://www.startpage.com/han/company-faq.html#q8)

Comment: Thank you.How do you found this FAQ? Is only a web search for "startpage FAQ"?I can't found this FAQ in their home page.